# Mysql "INSERT INTO" error throw with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I use the following code using mysql with Node.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var db = mysql.createConnection({host:'localhost', user:'root', password: 'pw', database: 'db'});
db.connect();
```

And, I use this to SELECT data and handle error.

```
db.query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE uid = ? LIMIT 1", [selfid], function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // do something....
});
```

But, I want to ask that when I use "INSERT" and some error happens, will the app.js crash if I haven't handle error?

```
var qstr = "INSERT INTO user_info (uid, message, created_time) VALUES(?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
db.query(qstr, [uid, message]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the app will not crash if you do not handle your errors. It will continue silently. It is up to you to catch the errors and handle them.

```
var qstr = "INSERT INTO user_info syntax error";
db.query(qstr, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("A wild error appeared!", err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
});
```